# How to create stages dynamically / concatenate closures?

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

What i want to achieve is building a list of stages with avoiding using when{}. Im trying to run parallel pipelines

Here is example code

```
def stage_pull = {
        stage('pulling') {
            echo 'pulling'
        }
    }
 
def stage_build = {
        stage(pulling) {
            echo 'building'
        }
    }
 
def stage_deb = {
        stage(pulling) {
            echo 'deb file'
        }
    }
 
def transformIntoStages(stage1,stage2) {
    //return stage1 + stage2
    //return {stage1;stage2}
    return stage1 << stage2
}
 
def agent_list = ["agent1", "agent2"]
stepsForParallel = [:]
 
stepsForParallel['agent1'] = transformIntoStages(stage_pull,stage_build)
stepsForParallel['agent2'] = transformIntoStages(stage_pull,stage_deb)
 
pipeline{
    agent any
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages{
        stage('BUILD'){
            steps{
                script{
                    parallel stepsForParallel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is simplified version. In real project, the number of used stages will be different for each agent.

I also have version with closures inside methods ...
https://pastebin.com/gPJjPx59

But none of this work.
PS. I know matrix{}, i use it often but I dont want to use it in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed to achieve the goal by using strings and evaluate() function.

```
def stage_pull() {
    return """
        stage('pulling') {
            echo 'pulling'
        }
    """
    }
 
def stage_build() {
    return """
        stage('building') {
            echo 'building'
        }
    """
    }
 
def stage_deb() {
        return """
        stage('deb') {
            echo 'deb file'
        }
        """
    }
 
def transformIntoStages(stage1,stage2) {
    echo "{" + stage1 + stage2 + "}"
    return {  evaluate(stage1 + stage2) }
}
 
stepsForParallel = [:]
 
stepsForParallel['agent1'] = transformIntoStages(stage_pull(),stage_build())
stepsForParallel['agent2'] = transformIntoStages(stage_pull(),stage_deb())
stepsForParallel['agent3'] = transformIntoStages(stage_pull(),'')
 
pipeline{
    agent any
    options {
        timestamps()
    }
    stages{
        stage('BUILD'){
            steps{
                script{
                    parallel stepsForParallel
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However im afraid that in case of more complicated stages/functions/structures with different kinds of parenthesis it will start to be a mess. And Blue Ocean cant show this properly. But in logs with timestamps and most of all in "Pipeline Steps" section i can see that it works as it should.

So im still open to some suggestions